# Bulk save() of several objects - updates and creates with hierarchy

Tags: python, arrays, json, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to create objects from json while validating it. BUT I don't want to literally insert or update them into DB in case JSON will contain wrong format or even unacceptable number (in arrays) and trying to collect all these objects into array and at the end save it (code is below). JSON looks like this

```
{
"id": "a1ab2759-e947-4a59-aa82-1e558f1693ca",
"puzzle_played": [[135, 136, 137],[138, 139, 140],[141,144,146]]
}
```

Top level is puzzle_played. This object exists. Only one thing that I want is to update its submission date:

```
puzzle_played.submission_date = datetime.today
```

Then I'm reading JSON's array 'puzzle_played'. Every entire array there is cluster of points. So there is a hierarchy of items here like this (where I already have only puzzle_played, the rest objects I want to create)

```
puzzle_played
    +solution_cluster
        +cluster_point
        +cluster_point
    +solution_cluster
        [...]
```

What I'm doing is (I skipped validation steps)

```
    objects_to_save = []
    puzzle_played_id = request.data['id']

    pp = get_object_or_404(Puzzles_Played, pk = puzzle_played_id)

    pp.date_submitted = datetime.today()

    #I DO NOT save it, but put it in the array for latter 'bulk' save 
    objects_to_save.append(pp)

    puzzle_played = request.data['puzzle_played']

    counter = 0
    for _i in puzzle_played:

        sc = Solution_Cluster(puzzle_played = pp, cluster = counter)
        #I DO NOT save it, but put it in the array for latter 'bulk' save 
        objects_to_save.append(sc)
        for _j in _i:
            point = get_object_or_404(Point, pk = _j)
            cp = Cluster_Point(solution_cluster = sc, point = point)
            objects_to_save.append(cp)


    for _obj in objects_to_save:
        _obj.save()
```

**The problem** is when I iterate over objects(objects_to_save) that I **almost** created - I have `(1048, "Column 'cluster_id' cannot be null")`. This happens on the first **cluster_point**, i.e. *first* object that I create with reference to the created parental object. That means there is some problem with parental solution_cluster (it was created successfully though). However, when I'm doing something like this:

```
   for _obj in objects_to_save:
        if isinstance(_obj, Cluster_Point):
            print(_obj,_obj.solution_cluster.id)
        _obj.save()
```

This prints me **non-null** values for solution_cluster_id, which makes me even more confused!
Then why do I have this error?

BTW explicitly save() objects right after operations with them works fine! Unfortunately it's not what I want...

Any help is very welcome! And sorry for long explanation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning a "solution_cluster" object to a "cluster_point" object. But the problem is that if you dont call `save()` method for your solution_cluster object `sc` , it will not has an ID, so doing this

```
cp = Cluster_Point(solution_cluster = sc, point = point)
#lather
cp.save()
```

no gonna works. when you referenced `sc`, it has not an ID.

> That means there is some problem with parental solution_cluster (it
>   was created successfully though).

Not, it was not created successfully, because you has not call `save()` method yet, so your `sc` object live in "memory" and has not a ID, and without an ID it can't be referenced as "parent".

Then, when you start to iterating through `objects_to_save` and save your first `sc` object, THAT object would has an ID, then, when you call `save()` over your `cp` object, that referenced `sc` object is not the same, it's a **"copy"** without an ID(here is the tricky part) and then you will get an error.

Comment: thank you for answer. My logic was - in memory - object refers to another object (kind of pointer). Therefore after save() operation for parental object, reference to the parental object is fine and contains ID... And as I mentioned at the end of my question - I printed the id, which will be missing... Could you clarify this?

Comment: @AlexanderB. because, `Solution_Cluster(puzzle_played = pp, cluster = counter)` is pointing to a new `sc` object. Is not the same.

Comment: does it mean that 

 object = Entity(id=1, [bla bla bla]);
 # object here is different;
 object.save();
 # than object here???

Comment: yeh, it looks like you're correct... However it looks to  dark magic. If create p=Parent() and after this c=Child(parent=p), and only after this save it, it will give me some error, however if I do p.save(), and after this print(c.parent.id), you will get real id... That means it supposed to exist...

Comment: I ended up with some magic trick inside the last loop over objects_to_save(), however your explanation is absolutely correct.

Comment: @AlexanderB. Ah nice, also, you should check django [bulk_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create)

Comment: Thanks, it's useful but only for the same Object type. If there will be parent-child... It will not gonna work. Anyways, thank you!